# document.getElementById или зависимость содержания одного текстового поля от другого

Tags: php, javascript, html

Имеется текстовое поле, которое содержит в себе имя проекта и выглядит оно так:

```
$err=$my->out_branch_read("./project/".$name .".txt", "Name");
    if ($my->out_branch_read!="")
        echo "<input type='text' id='ftp1' onkeyup='repeatTextFtp()' maxlength='25' size='100' name='new_project' value='$my->out_branch_read'></p>";
    else
        echo "<input type='text' id='ftp1' onkeyup='repeatTextFtp()' maxlength='25' size='100' name='new_project'></p>";
```

Также имеется поле, которое содержит путь к внешним ресурсам:

```
$all_resurs="";
    $err=$my->out_branch_read("./project/".$name .".txt", "Ftp");
    if ($my->out_branch_read!=""){
        echo "<p style='margin:20px'> <input type='checkbox' name='ftp' value='true' checked onclick='return ShowArea(this.form, 35)'>Копирование на общедоступный ресурс и на FTP</p>";
        if ($my->out_branch_read=="true")
            $all_resurs="";
            else $all_resurs=$my->out_branch_read;
        echo "<div id=resurs_b style='display:block; margin:30px'>
            <div class='name'>Общедоступный ресурс: 
            <div class='cmd'><input type='text' id='ftp2' maxlength='250' size='80' name='all_resurs' value='$all_resurs' ></div></div>";
```

**и т.д. ( остальное не столь важно, там остался else)**

Таким образом, если имя проекта называется TEST_1, то путь к ресурсу будет, например такой \\STORE\MYCATALOG\Branches\04\TEST_1

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при изменение имени проекта, его имя менялось и в пути к ресурсу. Делаю я это так:

```
function repeatTextFtp() {
    if (document.getElementById("ftp1").value=="$name"){
        document.getElementById("ftp2").value='$_POST["all_resurs"]';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("ftp2").value='"\\\\STORE\\MYCATALOG\\Branches\\04".$_POST[new_project].""';
    }
}
```

$name это уже записанное в TEST_1.txt имя проекта, то есть старое его имя. 
 Но, путь всё время так и записывается, т.е. "\\STORE\MYCATALOG\Branches\04".$_POST[new_project].""

В силу своей неопытности я скорей всего document.getElementById("ftp2").value присваиваю неправильно сформированное значение или же переменные $name и $_POST[new_project] нужно объявить ранее. 
Может есть другие способы реализации, не такие громоздкие. **Ведь мне важно учесть, чтобы поле с ресурсом можно было и вручную менять в независимости от имени проекта. И вообще, как я поняла, $_POST это же php-ешный метод. А в javascript как он записывается/используется?**

Comment: для соеденения строк в php используесся точка, а в javascript плюс

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk а с кавычками нет проблем? Например, в if они вообще нужны для $name и $_POST и вообще, а POST, наверное, в  javascript не будет работать, да?

Comment: Вы вообще смешали в одном коде 2 языка программирования.  Я не очень силен в javasctipt но там скорее всего нужно так присваивать значение атрибуту value `document.getElementById("ftp1").setAttribute(value, "некоторое значение")`. Ели у вас $name переменная то тогда кавычки не нужны, но в  javasctipt переменные задаются не так как в php. $_POST в javasctipt не нужен так как он работает на стороне клиента, а $_POST это вариант отправки данных серверу.

Comment: Попробуйте вот так `function repeatTextFtp() {     document.getElementById("ftp2").value='\\\\STORE\\MYCATALOG\\Branches\\04\\'+document.getElementById("ftp1").value;
}`. Не оформляю ответом, так как не уверен в нем.